suddenly very slow, high cpu for many normal tasks
My Linux Mint Lenovo Thinkpad e14 is unrecognizable after booting today. Many simple tasks take 5+ times longer than they used to, and my CPU is much much higher than it used to be for the same tasks. Examples: tab switcher, right click, opening firefox, thunderbird, sublime, etc.

I ran sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade after this started but it did not help
I've rebooted several times
Yesterday, I installed at least 1 new R packages as root, and accessed a remote HPC cluster for the first time
I booted into Windows 10 (dual boot) and everything seemed fine there, suggesting hardware is OK?

... Not sure if any of that is relevant
output of inxi -Fxxxrz:
System:    Kernel: 5.15.0-105-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 wm: muffin 4.8.1 
           dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20TA004HUS v: ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 20TA004HUS v: SDK0J40697 WIN serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO v: R1EET56W(1.56 ) date: 06/29/2023 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 16.6 Wh condition: 45.8/45.0 Wh (102%) volts: 11.1/11.1 model: LGC 5B10X026 type: Li-poly 
           serial: <filter> status: Discharging cycles: 2794 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 
           L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 44851 
           Speed: 727 MHz min/max: 400/4700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 492 2: 609 3: 1038 4: 446 5: 652 6: 588 7: 979 8: 667 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:9a49 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:a0c8 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.0-105-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 4000 bus ID: 00:14.3 chip ID: 8086:a0f0 
           IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 
           bus ID: 04:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 295.75 GiB (62.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZALQ512HALU-000L1 size: 476.94 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 
           serial: <filter> rev: BL1QFXV7 scheme: GPT 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 342.50 GiB used: 295.71 GiB (86.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6 
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 977.0 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): fan-1: 0 
Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ppa-focal.list 
           1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/inkscape_dev-stable-focal.list 
           1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu focal main
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mendeleydesktop.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
           1: deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/linuxmint-packages ulyssa main upstream import backport
           2: deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
           3: deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           4: deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
           6: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list 
           1: deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list 
           1: deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-gimp-focal.list 
           1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gimp/ubuntu focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zotero.list 
           1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/zotero-archive-keyring.gpg by-hash=force] https://zotero.retorque.re/file/apt-package-archive ./
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/librewolf.sources 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://deb.librewolf.net focal main
Info:      Processes: 272 Uptime: 27m Memory: 15.32 GiB used: 2.21 GiB (14.4%) Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.4.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.38 

Any guidance on how to track down the source of this sudden slow-down is appreciated.
FYI: cross posted here
Edit 1 additional info:

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor | sort -u:

powersave


lscpu | grep MHz:

CPU MHz:                            2800.000
CPU max MHz:                        4700.0000
CPU min MHz:                        400.0000

While it's in powersave mode, I don't think this is the issue, since the cpu is still ~60% and it does not explain the degree of slowdown.

Please [edit] your question and add the output of cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor | sort -u, my first guess is that you have the powesave governor on. What is your CPU frequency? See lscpu | grep MHz. Also, does pressing Fn+H help? Some Lenovo models use Fn+H and Fn+M to switch between CPU speeds.

Thanks -- see reply in edited question.

Does running echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor help?

No. Opening thunderbird after still took 30+ seconds, used to take <5.

And has it stuck? If you now do cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor are all lines showing performance? Is the lscpu output different now? And did you try Fn+H?

Yes it stuck, though with performance the idle rate was still 2800. However, I just did watch -n1 "lscpu | grep MHz" while opening thunderbird again, and cpu crawled to <500 during the spike. So it seems like a bottleneck or something?

I've been having serious issues with my P14s and I had to install thinkfan and tweak thermald. Have a look at these links which helped me: 1, 2, 3 and probably the most informative: 4.

Begin with the most obvious: top. Is something else running and slowing you down? Next: df -h: is anything full? Anything in /var/log/syslog?

Nothing suspicious in top except that processes seem to need way more cpu than normal (e.g. opening librefolf took ~50% of 8 cores for >30 sec!). df -h seems fine, I have 30G free.

Thanks @terdon -- I pressed Fn+H but nothing happened. How can I check it worked? Re. throttling, that seems like a possible culprit. Any idea how that might have become enabled overnight?

The high percentage is expected with throttlilng since the same process is taking the same "amount" of CPU but since there is less CPU to go around, the same amount corresponds to a higher percentage. As for what could have happened overnight, no idea. Maybe an update that disabled thermald? This really sounds like the throttling issues I've seen so that last link, the github repo, has good suggestions. Don't use the actual program from the repo, read the description and do what it suggests.

Apparently I can't run thermald: systemctl status thermald.service returns [/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/dytc_lapmode] present: Thermald can't run on this platform. I also noticed that my CPU temp (sensors) is 48C when completely idle, and basically never exceeds 52C (due to throttling). Could this be a hardware issue?

@jessexknight yeah, read the links closely, there's a lot of information there. The relevant bit is that you need to "add the --ignore-cpuid-check to the ExecStart line  in /lib/systemd/system/thermald.service as mentioned in links 2 and 4 (sorry I'm not being clearer, I don't know the full details and I am just trying to remember what I did a while back for my hardware from my notes). Then run systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart thermald.service. If any of this stuff works, I can try and post an answer but let's see if it's the right direction first.

Thanks. I followed the instructions and even rebooted after modifying thermald.service. The daemon still says it does not run (Active: inactive (dead) since... either boot time or last time I tried systemctl restart thermald.service) because I have dytc_lapmode file - some goofy laptop service to avoid leg burns I guess. Do you think I can safely remove this file /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/dytc_lapmode ?

Solution: I installed throttled and had to disable SecureBoot in BIOS to make it work.
It seems many users have this issue, only on Linux. My case is possibly unique in that it started suddenly. It's a shame no proper fix is available after 5+ years. Thanks for the help in the comments above.
